# How can I get one type of the child from a list by lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is the code:

```
private struct Child {
        public string A;
        public string B;
        public boolean C;
}
List<Child> Test=new List<Child>();
```

Now I want to get all the `string` A from the `List<Child> Test`.

I have to do it like this yet:

```
List<string>NewList=new List<string>();
foreach(Child C in Test)
{
NewList.Add(C.A);
}
```

It is so troublesome that I wanna whether there is a way faster, for example by using the lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: ```List<String> newList= Test.Select(x => x.A).ToList();```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var NewList = Test.Select(x => x.A).ToList();
```

but this is not faster, only a little less code.

Comment: Well, that's what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this Answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1178913/3121280

you can do it like this:

```
NewList = Test.Select(
    x => x.A 
).ToList();
```

Comment: `c#` is a case sensitive language. `.select` is NOT the same as `.Select`.

Comment: @AFract I have 19k rep, and I could have edited it myself. It is generally frowned upon to edit other people's code in their posts, and instead help them understand why the post is incorrect, or perhaps misinterpreted. (Perhaps he meant using a `.select` from a different library?)

Comment: @FrankerZ I didn't looked your own reputation, only mohRamadan's, who is a newcomer. He's giving himself a link to an answer that relies on native Linq "Select" method, there's absolutely no reason here to use another library, and method names in C# starts with caps. So for me it was obviously a typo and it seemed useful to improve the post just by fixing it. But I agree regarding your arguments in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` shown by others is what you need here, but it's worth mentioning [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) for the moments where you need granchildren.

```
private class Child
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var children = new List<Child>(){
        new Child{
            Name = "C1",
            Children = new List<Child>{
                new Child{ Name = "C1_C1"},
                new Child{ Name = "C1_C2"}
            }},
        new Child{
            Name = "C2",
            Children = new List<Child>{
                new Child{ Name = "C2_C1"},
                new Child{ Name = "C2_C2"}
            }}
        };

    var granchildren = children.SelectMany( c => c.Children);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", granchildren.Select(c => c.Name)));
}
```

The snippet above outputs the following:

```
C1_C1, C1_C2, C2_C1, C2_C2
```

Comment: Nor related to the question, but always useful to know. I've seen too much C# developers that were not aware of SelectMany().